# Can anti-gravity lead to thickness of any liquid?

Tags: gravity, fluid-statics

I came across an advertisement that said this juice is this because of [anti-gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-gravity) formula.

Comment: So, this company has invented anti-gravity, and the best application they could come up with is... thickening juice?

Comment: Hi. I suspect the ad simply means that the juice has a thickening agent that prevents solids suspended in the juice from falling downwards due to gravity. So it isn't *anti-gravity* in the sense that physicists use the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Anti-gravity is not a thing, and juices don't have 'thickness' as an intrinsic property.

Commercials don't usually do physics, they just jumble words together.

Comment: Sometimes "thick" is a synonym for "viscous."